# 86 Trans Am stalls after hard driving when coming to a stop

Tags: pontiac

My 86 Trans Am fuel injected 305 is a beast but after hard driving I come to a slow stop and it will stall either while stopped or stopping. It starts right back up tho and never occurs any other time. New plugs dist rotor and module. 117 k

Comment: Which 305 does this have, the normal, HO, or SPFI?

Comment: Normal I believe

Comment: If it's fuel injected, it's not the "normal" (I don't remember seeing that the first time I read this), it would be Sequential Port Fuel Injection (SPFI). Was thinking if it was carbureted, it might have a problem with fuel pressure or carb bowl not getting refilled correctly. This is definitely a fuel issue. Your fuel pump may be going bad, where it's becoming too warm and dropping fuel pressure after the driving. You can check this with a fuel pressure gauge on the engine while driving. You need to tape the gauge where you can see it while driving, though, outside of the engine cabin.

Comment: I plan on sending it to a shop to check that. In the mean time could it be low idle? Since prev owner took compressor off the belt ot may be having issues. I will try and turn it up today and see

Comment: If you are talking about the A/C compressor, there shouldn't be any issue with idle or how it runs, as long as all the other accessories are still in place on the serpentine belt (water pump and alternator), but in order to do that, it would have to have an "idler pulley" put in place to replace it. If you are talking about the smog pump, this should not cause you any issues with idle either. All it does it pumps air into the exhaust to ensure the catalytic convertor to heat up faster right after startup to help it not become plugged.

Comment: The ac compressor correct but he just rerouted without a pully and put on a smaller belt

Comment: Gotcha, but this still should not be causing you any issues as you've described.